# Trying to achieve skewed menu items without skewed text. Came close but 2nd tier items are cascading strangely

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used '`transform`' to skew the `li` items, then opposite transform on the `span`s to straighten out the text.

I had to use jQuery to add the `span`s around the text because the CMS I have to use at work automatically creates the menu, so I can't add any classes or `span`s within the HTML.

I have come close to achieving what I want, but the drop down menu items are cascading for some reason.

How can I fix this?

Here is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/y5w8m/1/

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="current first"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>drop 1</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>drop 2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>drop 2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>drop 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>drop 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>drop 1</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>drop 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>drop 2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Main Navigation */
#menu {
    background: #528aaf;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    z-index: 400;
}
ul#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

ul#nav > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(-25deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-25deg);
}

ul#nav li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2D5B79;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 35px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#nav li a span {
    transform: skew(25deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(25deg);
    display:block;
}

ul#nav li.current a,
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background: #c68c67;
}

ul#nav li ul { /* second-level lists */
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: -999em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isnt read by screen readers */
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}   

ul#nav li ul li a, 
ul#nav li.current ul li a { 
    background: #2F2F2F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    transform: skew(25deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(25deg);
    display:block;
}
ul#nav li ul li,
ul#nav li ul li span {
    transform: skew(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0deg);
    display:block;
}
ul#nav li ul li a:hover, 
ul#nav li.current ul li a:hover,
ul#nav li ul li.current a { /* second level dropdown button hover state */  
    background: #c68c67;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#nav li ul li ul {
    margin: -30px 0 0 220px;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul li ul,
ul#nav li:hover ul li ul li ul,
ul#nav li.sfhover ul li ul,
ul#nav li.sfhover ul li ul li ul {
    left: -999em;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul,
ul#nav li ul li:hover ul,
ul#nav li ul li ul li:hover ul,
ul#nav li.sfhover ul,
ul#nav li ul li.sfhover ul,
ul#nav li ul li ul li.sfhover ul { /* lists nested under hovered list items */
    left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're wanting to achieve (the positioning of the drop downs may need a bit of tweaking)? http://jsfiddle.net/jzKHD/

The skew on the top level items is also affecting the bounds of the drop down `ul` -- you're then "unskewing" each drop down `li`, whereas you should actually unskew the whole `ul`:

```
ul#nav li ul { /* second-level lists */
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: -999em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because
                     display: none isnt read by screen readers */
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* This transform was moved here from the next rule */
    -webkit-transform: skew(25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(25deg);
    transform: skew(25deg);
}   

ul#nav li ul li a, 
ul#nav li.current ul li a { 
    background: #2F2F2F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    display:block;
    /* The transform in the previous rule was originally here */
}
```

---

**EDIT**: To make it work correctly with the third level nav, move the transform into a separate rule that only affects the first drop down (using child selectors). So the set of styles above would instead look like this:

```
ul#nav li ul { /* second-level lists */
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: -999em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isnt read by screen readers */
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* This rule will only affect the first drop down, and be ignored by subsequent ones. */
ul#nav > li > ul {
    -webkit-transform: skew(25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(25deg);
    transform: skew(25deg);
}

ul#nav li ul li a, 
ul#nav li.current ul li a { 
    background: #2F2F2F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    display:block;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ns832/ (Again, I've ignored the spacing issues, they should be hopefully easy enough to fix.)

Comment: Thank you! This definitely solved the first drop down. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix the 3rd level drop down? It seems this is causing that one to skew the opposite way.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise there was a third level. If you use a child selecter you should be able to only apply the skew to the second level. In my original answer it skew every nested level -- so the first drop down would be correct, and the second drop down is "over-skewed". Will update my answer and JSFiddle.